# How to enable PyCharm Type Checker feature for cython(.pyx) file?

Tags: python, pycharm, cython, mypy

It seems python type checker in PyCharm automatically works for `.py` files.. but not for `.pyx` files.

Is there any way to enable type checker for `.pyx` files in PyCharm?

Also, is there any way to use mypy with cython files (`.pyx` files)?

Answer (score 1):

The .pyx file is regarded as a text file by default in Pycharm. However, you can change the setting. Go to File->Settings->Editor->File Types. In recognized file types, find "Text", delete the entry "*.pyx" in the registered patterns. Then, find "Python" in the recognized file types, add an entry "*.pyx" in the registered patterns.